# Unity Hololens SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, soap, hololens

I have a `SOAP` web service to communicate with. In command line (`wsdl`) I've managed to generate a client code. It relies upon `System.Web` and `System.Web.Services`. So I have create a "Plugins" folder and put both *DLLs* there (took from `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.0b2\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.7.1-api` in my case). I've tried to use the web service by calling one of the method and it all works in Editor, I'm able to get a parsed response. So I've made a Build and Deployed to the *HL1*. All good, but the app crashes when I press the button to call a web service method. This is an exception info: `"The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access."`.
Could someone help me to understand the issue. Maybe we have someone who successfully implemented SOAP on Hololens?

---

Edit:

So I've found that instead of copying *DLLs* into the "Plugins" folder, you can create a file called `csc.rsp` inside the "Assets" folder and put references inside it like so:

```
-r:System.Web.dll
-r:System.Web.Services.dll
```

And it seems to be working correctly, again, only in Editor. Good thing is that it is not crashing on Hololens now, it just does nothing, after I press the button to use the Web Service it just does nothing. Probably I need to connect the debugger and see what happens on the device. Gonna try tomorrow morning...

---

Update:

So this is an exception raised on Hololens:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol::.ctor occurred
```

Does it have something to do with the fact that my endpoint is `http` and not `https`? (edited)

Comment: I found this link(http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Unity_-_SOAP_Interaction), as the author said, “SOAP and other web services only work for standalone builds”. It seems that this solution cannot be built on the UWP platform.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT in the article he wanted to use it on Web, there are other limitations for the Web, in particular whatever uses threads won't work, so .NET networking libraries won't work. As for UWP, it supported pretty much all .NET when there was .NET scripting backend, now it is deprecated in favor of il2cpp and everything from .NET is compiled to c++ I guess, therefore some libraries are not working out of the box..

Comment: Yes, because now UWP only support IL2CPP. This happens most likely because of IL2CPP. Could you file this as an issue to Unity Communtiy? They may be faster to find a solution or understand what's wrong.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I've posted it on Unity forum as well: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1670803/uwp-hololens-soap-web-service.html